# self-issued exchange certificate for dyndns-url

Tags: exchange-2007, dyndns, certificate

I've got an exchange server behind behind a port to address translation firewall.
The server is reachable from the internet using a dyndns-url.

Now I want to sync windows phones to exchange mailboxes. To achieve this, I need to install the exchange certificate on the windows phone (send it to the phone by mail, double click). So far so good.
But, as far as I can see this does only work if the certificate on my exchange server matches the dyndns-url?

So I'd like to know: how do I create a self signed certificate for my dyndns-url and install it on exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though you can have a self signed certificate, it will be good if you get a domain name and a proper ucc san cert from either godaddy or http://www.exchangecertificates.com/

create a UCC self-signed certificate. We will require the following names:

## NETBIOS name of Exchange: EX-2k7 (example)

## Internal FQDN: EX-2k7.abc.local (example)

## External FQDN (Public name): dyndns-hostname (example) (use nslookup/ping to verify the external FQDN)

## Autodiscover name: autodiscover.dyndns-hostname (example)

## SubjectName: cn=dyndns-hostname (example)

In EMS, run the following command to generate the new self-signed certificate:

`New-ExchangeCertificate -FriendlyName "SelfSigned Cert2010" -SubjectName "cn=domain name" -DomainName server netbios name,server.domain.local,dyndns-hostname,autodiscover.dyndns-hostname.com, -PrivateKeyExportable $True`

Next enable the certificate with Enable-ExchangeCertificate cmdlet. Enable atleast IIS and SMTP.

`Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -Services POP,IMAP,SMTP,IIS`

Next verify certificate has been installed using EMS/IIS Manager or both. (Sometimes you may have to remove the certificate and then install/enable certificate again).

where dyndns-host name = for e.g. "my.owndomain.net"

Hope that Helps

Comment: I'd buy a certificate, but is it possible to use a real certificate on a dialup line with dynamic IP? A fixed IP is way too expensive at my provider.

Comment: Unless you write the actual IP address in the certificate it won't matter. The point of using a DNS entry for this is because the certificate matches against its common name and if the common name is a DNS entry, then it doesn't matter what IP it resolves to, you're never going to compare it.